# Crash on device, but debugger has nothing to say

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't determine the cause of a crash.

While running the debug build of an app on an iPad 3.1 from Xcode, the app terminates but the debugger doesn't tell me anything.  I have an all-exceptions breakpoint and that has certainly worked in the past to catch errors.

Not that I know how to use a crash dump, but when this happens the "Device Log" in the organizer devices pane shows an entry from process "Unknown" of type "Unknown".

I am also having memory warning problems, but in this case I'm not getting the memory warning method invoked (I have a log message and a breakpoint).  Could this be a memory warning that doesn't invoke the method ever?  [The memory warnings are a puzzle since Instruments isn't showing me any leaks and my own image objects aren't (obviously) being kept in memory -- but that's another problem].

Any idea what is happening to me and how I could get the debugger to trap the condition?

Comment: Is the crash happening while the app is running or while you are trying to start it up?

Comment: I'm running for a while (scrolling through a bunch of images) and something I do triggers the crash.

Comment: Is your app using ARC? What ios version is that? Does it happen on the simulator too? What do you do in your app that consumes that much memory?

Comment: Try enabling Zombie objects (google it) and see if that turns up anything useful. Crashes like this are often due to the OS killing your app at an inopportune time.

Comment: Using ARC, the iPad is running iOS6.1.3.  I have not reproduced the problem on the simulator as it is difficult to reproduce my (large) image data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your app is getting killed by the system because you allocate too much memory. Depending on how much memory you are allocating, it could very well happen that you never see the memory warning methods being called.

Check your app with instruments running and also check the crash report again, it should give you some more details. E.g. a list of processes with `rpages`, `recent_max` and `(state)` columns, with `Largest process:` shown above. I bet your process is named and also shows the state `(suspended)`, which means: iOS killed it because you allocated too much memory.